# ASP.NET Session doesn't persist when navigating to another site and back?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session

I have an ASP.NET MVC (not Core) web app that uses another site to authenticate the user, which involves navigating to the other site and back. I store information in the Session variable that I want to read after the user comes back to the original site, but the session when the user comes back is a new one, not the one I stored the information in.

Why/how is ASP.NET deciding to start a new session (or not remember the old one)? Is there some way to make it behave the way I want?

Comment: As long as you give your site chance to set cookies all should be good. Even redirecting to another site should be fine - looking at actual HTTP requests (i.e. dev tools in browser or Fiddler) should shed some light on what is going on. (Note that without exact details about your case the question is not answerable - session state indeed  designed to work exactly as you want)

Comment: Good suggestion to look at the traffic, that made it fairly easy to figure out. I've posted the answer for those who come upon this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I've figured this out. The problem is that the authentication site's page does a POST to return to the original site. The ASP.NET session cookie has SameSite=Lax, so a cross-site POST like this won't send it. Since ASP.NET doesn't see the cookie, it creates a new session and associated cookie, overwriting the original one.

The solution (or **a** solution, anyway), is to mark the cookie as SameSite=None and Secure, which I did by adding the following to my Web.config:

```
<sessionState cookieSameSite="None" />
<httpCookies requireSSL="true" />
```

The first line makes the session cookie SameSite=None, and the second line makes *all* cookies to Secure.